# Performance Issue with writing Spark Dataframes to Oracle Database

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I am trying to write to save a Spark DataFrame to Oracle. The save is working but the performance seems to be very poor.

I have tried 2 approaches using

1. `dfToSave.write().mode(SaveMode.Append).jdbc(…)`  --  I suppose this uses below API internally.
2. `JdbcUtils.saveTable(dfToSave,ORACLE_CONNECTION_URL, "table",props)`

Both seem to be taking very long, more than 3 mins for size of 400/500 rows DataFrame.

I hit across a JIRA SPARK-10040 , but says it is resolved in 1.6.0 and I am using the same.

Anyone has faced the issue and knows how to resolve it?

Comment: How many records are you inserting and how long does it take ?.

Comment: He said 3 minutes for 500 records. Even I admit that is slow for Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

I can tell you what happened to me. I turned down my partitions to query the database, and so my previously performant processing (PPP) became quite slow. However, since my dataset only collects when I post it back to the database, I (like you) thought there was a problem with the spark API, driver, connection, table structure, server configuration, anything. But, no, you just have to repartition after your query.

Comment: @lon Freeman, would you please explain more? how to do repartition? Thanks.

Comment: @M_Gh It's a method on dataset. I may not understand your question.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#repartition(numPartitions:Int,partitionExprs:org.apache.spark.sql.Column*):org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[T] You do a spark.read.jdbc with a low number of partitions, then call repartition.

Comment: thank you for your guidance. I knew about **repartition** but it will result more shuffling and take a lot of time.

Comment: Ha! You have to do a count or something to force it to act in a small number of partitions. Repartitioning like shuffling takes time,  but much less time than trying to get Oracle to respond to 400 clients